# A neutral word for someone who behaves differently from everyone else

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-in-context

What do you call a person, that, given a particular social context, behaves or is led to behave differently from all others, perhaps ending up being regarded as a strange person and/or punished or ending up as an outcast for his/her actions?

The terms "deviant", "freak", and "weirdo" exist, but I am looking for a word with a neutral rather than negative connotation. The word "deviant" also seems like it could imply a sexual context, which is not what I'm after.

What I don't like about these words is that a person coming across these is likely to dismiss the speaker or argument, killing the argument without giving out any further attention or consideration, which is not the effect I'm after.

I would like a word that summons interest in the person's unusual behavior, without putting the reader or luster off and create an atmosphere of interest I such person's behavior.

Comment: _"....marches to the beat of her own drum."_

Comment: "Has becoming rich changed you?" the reporter asked. "Well, in some ways," he replied. "I'm now 'eccentric' when I used to be 'weird', and 'delightfully witty' when I used to be 'rude'."

Comment: My daughter once commented that there as a group in her school who "want to be non-conformists -- just like all their friends".

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for words synonymous with **different** but without negative connotations you might try these:

> eccentric, individualist, unconventional, off-center, free spirit, nonconformist, recusant, bohemian, freethinker

Comment: I agree with eccentric, individualist, unconventional, and non-conformist. "Freethinker" is often used as a synonym for "atheist". (By atheists, anyway.) "Free spirit" has connotations of being a hippie. "Bohemian" has connotations of beatnik. "Recusant" I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Eccentric is a good one.  It's our nicest world for weird.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the adjective *[unconventional](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unconventional)*. For example,

> Jasper was an **unconventional** boy who always did things differently
>   from others. As a result, his talents were never recognised.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto @kartooniks on eccentric, individualist, unconventional, and non-conformist.

Other possibilities are maverick, offbeat, and unorthodox.

If the person is actively working against conventions, you might call him a rebel, a heretic, or an iconoclast.

Comment: I came here to suggest "maverick".

Answer (score 0):

While not a single word, a neutral description of such a person would be:

> She does her own thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try **outlier** (noun):

> a person or thing differing from all other members of a particular group or set. (NOAD)

It's very neutral to me. A person can be an outlier because they excel or because they're held back. When I think of the word, I imagine a [point on a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) that's far away from the others.